# Detailed Changelog for .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, changelog

Is there a detailed list of changes in .NET 4.0?

Please add any changes you know about.

Comment: This post really ought to be a Community Wiki post -- it's asking for a compilation of answers, which is something that CW is for.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883440/net-framework-4-0-documentation doesn't even mention changes.

Comment: @SLaks, no but this covers the same ground. Any changelog will be in the documentation. It's not word for word, but is concept-for-concept.

Comment: @SLaks "New Features" in .NET 4.0 are by their definition 'changes', as are any 'bugs fixed'. :-)

Comment: And to answer your question, it *is* available in the documentation, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @George: You're right; I hadn't seen that.  You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Changelog for .NET Framework 4.0 is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

From beta 1 but a good start [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/05/21/a-quick-analyze-of-the-net-fx-v4-0-beta1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've found in Beta 2.

If you know of any specific changes, feel free to add them.

## mscorlib

- `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView` – Explicit access to 32 or 64 bit registries.
- `System.AggregateException` – Thrown by the new parallelism stuff
- `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolderOption)` – Force creation or ignore existence
- `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` & `Environment.Is64BitProcess`
- `Environment.SystemPageSize` – Size of the system pagefile
- `System.Lazy<T>`  – Fully controlled lazy initialization
- `ResolveEventArgs.RequestingAssembly`  –  See which assembly is trying to load a dependency.
- `TimeZoneInfo` and supporting types moved to mscorlib
- `Tuple` – Generic tuples with up to 8 members
- `Type.IsEquivalentTo` – Check whether two COM types have the same identity
- `Type.IsEnumDefined` – Self-explanatory
- `Version.Parse` and `Version.TryParse`
- `Enum.HasFlag` and `Enum.TryParse<TEnum>`
- `Guid.Parse`, `Guid.ParseExact`, `Guid.TryParse`, and `Guid.TryParseExact`
- `+` and `-` operators for `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr`
- `Func` and `Action` in mscorlib with up to 16 parameters
- `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace

Comment: No idea, but was possibly interpreted as rep gaming? You post a question and answer it too? Best to mark it Community Wiki then I guess. Especially as you want people to keep editing and adding to it as they find changes.

Comment: I was trying to demonstrate the kind of answer that I'm looking for.  I don't have the time to do this for the entire framework, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: You don't have to defend yourself to me @SLaks, it wasn't me who voted. I'm just suggesting a reason why it *might* have been downvoted. 's All.

Comment: "I don't have the time to do this for the entire framework..", which makes it even more of a clear collaborative effort you're after, so CW is more appropriate.